# Not getting login with jwt in return auth failed

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, authentication, mongoose-schema

It's been hours since I am trying to figure this out but unable to find solution for it.

I have created `login` route , where I want to pass details of the entire object in which the user/admin lies. Somehow it is in nested structure so, I am not able to figure this out. I can do this with single schema structure.

**Login route:-**

```
router.post('/:compId/admin/login' , (req, res, next) => {

        Admin.find({ 'admins.email': req.body.email} , {companyID: req.params.compId})
        .exec()
        .then(admin => {
            if(admin.admins.length < 1) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: "Auth failed. admin not found."
                })
            }
            else{
                    console.log("nothing happened");    
                }
            bcryptt.compare(req.body.admins.password, admin.admins[0].password, (err, result) =>{
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({
                    message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                    });             
                }                   
                if (result && admin.admins[0].verified === "true"){
                    const adminEmaill = "ggh@xyz.com";                                                  //assaigning a user to admin 
                    const role2 = admin.admins[0].email===adminEmaill? "superadmin" : "admin";                  //check user id as admin or user
                    const token = jwt.sign( 
                        {
                            email: admin.admins[0].email,
                            phoneNo: admin.admins[0].phoneNumber,
                            role2,
                            comID: admin[0].companyID
                        },
                        process.env.JWT_KEY,
                        {
                            expiresIn : "1h"
                        });
                        return res.status(200).json({
                        message: "Auth Successful",
                        token : token
                        }); 
                }
                else{
                    console.log("admin is not verified");   
                    return res.json({
                    message: "Admin is not verified"
                    }); 
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            if (err.code == 500)
                        res.status(500).send(["Something went wrong in login"]);
                else
                return next(err);
        }); 
    });
```

**My controller :-**

```
var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.address = req.body.address;
    admin.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
    admin.admins = {
                    email : req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password, 
                    firstName : req.body.firstName, 
                    lastName : req.body.lastName,
                    phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber,
                    designation : req.body.designation,
                    role : "admin",
                    verified :"false",
                    users: []
    };
```

**This is my documents :-**

```
[{
    "admins": {
        "email": "angjun.34@test-mail.info",
        "password": "$2a$10$QgCJ4IaYXZK9JZIkLv2X9O/wnFpn0LEhFQujBco0M0TF2.X7OgDmW",
        "firstName": "hdsdsds",
        "lastName": "Ghodsdsdsh",
        "phoneNumber": "4544343",
        "designation": "Software Engineer",
        "role": "admin",
        "verified": "false",
        "users": [],
        "emailResetTokenn": "247c6e6794d15a311670da0bb13a4a8bf773b0e7f7b5dde0e555f421e2aef22f",
        "emailExpires": "2019-05-22T15:05:43.974Z",
        "saltSecret": "$2a$10$QgCJ4IaYXZK9JZIkLv2X9O"
    },
    "_id": "5ce510e7aca42c4c74fd9085",
    "companyName": "TEST",
    "address": "UAE",
    "contactDetails": "54534454",
    "companyID": "1223365",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "admins": {
        "email": "groham.224@test-mail.info",
        "password": "$2a$10$QgCJ9O/wnFpn0LEhFco0M0TF2.X7OgDmW",
        "firstName": "hdsdsds",
        "lastName": "Ghodsdsdsh",
        "phoneNumber": "4544343",
        "designation": "Software Engineer",
        "role": "admin",
        "verified": "false",
        "users": [],
        "emailResetTokenn": "247c6e6794d15a311670da0bb13a4a8bf773b0e7f7b5dde0e555f421e2aef22f",
        "emailExpires": "2019-05-22T15:05:43.974Z",
        "saltSecret": "$2a$10$QgCJ4IaYXZK9JZIkLv2X9O"
    },
    "_id": "5ce510e7aca42c4c74fd9085",
    "companyName": "RESTFUL Pvt Ltd",
    "address": "UK",
    "contactDetails": "54534454",
    "companyID": "155165",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

- Each company admin can pass only his/her entire company object.
- What changes should I make to return JWT token here ? AS of now I am not reaching out to server.
- Is it because my admins `if(admin.admins.length < 1)` is not in array ?

**EDIT:-** Tried this by changing url route but getting auth failed response over here.

```
bcryptt.compare(req.body.password, admin.admins.password, (err, result) =>{
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({
                    message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                    });             
                }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @MrfksIV I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information on what error you are getting it is not that easy to debug. One potential issue I see is this line:

```
if (result && admin.admins[0].verified === "true"){
```

If the `admins.verified` property of your document is a boolean, then the above line will always resolve to false and fallback to the `else` clause. So if this is the case, then remove the quotes:

```
if (result && admin.admins[0].verified === true){
```

Comment: No , I have defined this as a string in my model.

Comment: Whats the response you get from the server? Does your request reach the server?

Comment: No my request is not reaching the server. All I get is `Mongoose: admins.find({ 'admins.email': 'hokogere@max-mail.com' }, { projection: { companyID: '155165' } })` in my console. Also when I am changing `Admin.find` to `findOne` , then I am getting my else message that is "nothing happened"